# SPDY on shared host & SEO Semantics

Tags: seo, semantics, shared-hosting, spdy, http2

**NodeSPDY on shared host**

I got a webspace hosted by [uberspace](https://uberspace.de) and want to use NodeSPDY, but there is a loadbalancer in between which cuts off the tls connection.

On uberspace one can request a Port to be opened. With this port it is possible to request resources directly by adding the port to the domain (ie https://mydomain.de:1337/someresource.jpg). So every thing works out nice but i wonder:

- how about SEO semantics, will it harm my ranking?
- are there any better solutions for this problems?
- can i use ipv6 to mask the port somehow?

I know this is a stopgap but i wanted to get in touch with this technology and ease the work for changing to http2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how about SEO sematics, will it harm my ranking?

It won't.

> are there any better solutions for this problems?

It is not a problem.

> can i use ipv6 to mask the port somehow?

No.

Comment: thanks for your short and straight reply ;) **1.** its good to hear that this solution wont affect my seo ranking... **2** i was just wondering if there is another way to use spdy on a shared host, sorry if the question was not clear enoght **3** ok, just an idea